# Is it OK to use manufacturer vendor ID when using virtual COM port example?

Tags: microcontroller, usb, pic

I am using a PIC32mz microcontroller for a serial port emulator application. Example code is working fine.

But if I want to sell this product, do I need to get a new vendor ID? Is it OK to use the manufacturer vendor ID?

Comment: ask the manufacturer

Comment: The documentation of the PIC and the libraries should include the rules how to use the vendor ID. And you can visit the [USB organisation](https://www.usb.org/) for further information.

Comment: Thanks i am going to check it.

Comment: One thing to watch out for with USB VID/PID, is that changing the VID/PID may require some extra steps to match up the correct device driver. For windows PCs especially, the PC looks at USB VID/PID to determine which device driver (software) to use.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/80815/what-is-a-product-id-in-usb-and-do-i-need-to-buy-it-for-my-project

Comment: for sure at least once FTDI actively broke the driver for non-original FT232 chips; at least vendor has a PID selling program to aid in registration (you use their VID but with an unique PID assigned by them); to be 100% USB compliant you should get you VID *and* certify the board

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a product ID in USB and do I need to buy it for my project?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/80815/what-is-a-product-id-in-usb-and-do-i-need-to-buy-it-for-my-project)